# Terminal Services and Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

We have an internet facing server running Terminal Server on Windows 2008. When a someone uses the Windows XP or Windows 7 RDP client, (after they log in), how can I automatically redirect their session to connect to their own personal desktop instead of logging into the terminal server itself?

I know I could have then log into the termianl server & put a RDP icon to the own system on their desktop, but I would prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do some research on Microsoft's "Terminal Services Gateway". This would allow users to come in over SSL and use this server to access resources on the inside. Great care should be taken with the security design, but it's not that hard to implement. You will however need a publicly verifiable SSL certificate to put it in correctly.

Comment: In case someone finds this question and is on Server 2008 R2, this feature has been renamed to Remote Desktop Gateway, and that is the wording used on the advanced options pane in the Windows 7 RDC client.

Comment: Nice catch Jeff

Comment: I still had the Technet page for, Deploying Remote Desktop Gateway, in my clipboard from a previous post( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd983941%28WS.10%29.aspx ).